# Combining Filters with Pagination Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am having trouble combining filters whilst maintaining correct pagination.

I am using a custom directive and ng-repeat to cycle through tasks.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control search-icon float-right" placeholder="Type to filter">

<select ng-model="clientSearch">
    <option value="">All Clients</option>
    <option value="1">All Client 1</option>
    <option value="2">All Client 2</option>
    <option value="3">All Client 3</option>
</select>

<task-pane ng-repeat="task in filterList | start: (currentPage - 1) * perPage | limitTo: perPage | filter: {client_id : clientSearch || undefined}: true" task-data="task" modal-open="modalOpen(task.id)"></task-pane>

<uib-pagination total-items="filterList.length" items-per-page="20" next-text="Next" previous-text="Previous" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-link-numbers="true"></uib-pagination>
```

And my JS for Controller:

```
.controller('TasksArchiveController', ['$http', '$scope', '$filter', '$uibModal', function($http, $scope, $filter, $uibModal) {

$http.post('../assets/js/ajax/tasks_ajax_router.php', 'action=getArchive', config = {
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
})

    .then(function successCallBack(response) {

        $scope.tasks = response.data.task_data;

        $scope.perPage = 20;

        $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.$watch('searchText', function (term) {
            var obj = term;
            $scope.filterList = $filter('filter')($scope.tasks, obj);
            $scope.currentPage = 1;

        });

    }

}, function errorCallBack(response) {
    console.log(response);
})


}])

    .directive('taskPane', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '../../assets/task_archive_pane.html',
            scope: {
                task: '=taskData',
                modalOpen: '&modalOpen'
            }
        };
    })

    .filter('start', function () {
        return function (input, start) {
            if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        };
    })
```

When I type into searchFilter, filterList.length updates, therefore the total-items attribute of the pagination updates and the correct number of pages are shown and everything is in order.

However, using the clientSearch filter (updating the model by selecting from the dropdown) filters correctly, but I need to update the filterList length (presumably) so that the pagination is calculated properly.

EDIT: I have tried defining the uib-pagination attribute as the following, meaning it does always get the correct number of total items, yet the pagination still calculates the number of pages needed using the original number of items before filtering:

```
total-items="(filterList | filter: {client_id : clientSearch || undefined}: true | filter: {user_id: staffSearch.id || undefined }: true | filter: {department_id : departmentSearch || undefined}: true | filter: {task_type : typeSearch || undefined}: true).length"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why you don't use angular ui pagination bootstrap ?

Comment: @VladRadulescu - I am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you probably want to perform the `client_id` filter before the pagination filters. Otherwise when you filter, you'll get pages of various small sizes as the `client_id` filtering is being performed within each page. Also, when you make the change below to count the filter results, the count would be wrong as it would only count one page. So the order should be `filter:`, `start:`, `limitTo:`

Second, you need to store the results of the `client_id` filter in a variable lets say `filtered`, and the length of this is what should control the pagination via `total-items`.

```
<task-pane ng-repeat="task in filtered = (filterList | filter: {client_id : clientSearch || undefined}: true) | start: (currentPage - 1) * perPage | limitTo: perPage" task-data="task" modal-open="modalOpen(task.id)"></task-pane>

<uib-pagination total-items="filtered.length" items-per-page="20" next-text="Next" previous-text="Previous" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-link-numbers="true"></uib-pagination>
```

[Simplified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/yycdbhrr/)

Answer (score 0):

Better option to go for it would be using `variable alias` on filtered collection like `ng-repeat="item in items | filter1: param | filter: {prop: param1} as filteredItem"` where `as filteredItem` will store filtered value inside `filteredItem` scope variable and you can use that scope variable wherever you want.

**Markup**

```
<task-pane ng-repeat="task in filterList | start: (currentPage - 1) * perPage | limitTo: perPage | filter: {client_id : clientSearch || undefined}: true as filteredList" 
  task-data="task" modal-open="modalOpen(task.id)">
</task-pane>
```

**Pagination**

```
<uib-pagination total-items="filteredList.length" 
   items-per-page="20" next-text="Next" 
   previous-text="Previous" ng-model="currentPage" 
   max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" 
   boundary-link-numbers="true">
</uib-pagination>
```

> **Note**: This feature has been supported in Angular 1.3+

Comment: Hi. This doesn't work - it calculates filteredList as 20 each time, so there is never a page 2